# RSS Error: WP HTTP Error: Could not resolve host: wordpress.org

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

whenever i open my word press dashboard the 2 errors comes.
RSS Error: WP HTTP Error: Could not resolve host: wordpress.org
RSS Error: WP HTTP Error: Could not resolve host: planet.wordpress.org
Kindly help me how can i solve it.

Comment: google is your friend.  there are tons of pages referring to this exact error with multiple solutions.

Comment: thanks to inform me but i have not found solution thats why i asked it

Comment: describe what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

change .htaccess file to bellow

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```